# Import org package to Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I'm trying to build a project in java and I need to use org package , i need to import these

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

classes.
However intellij doesn't recognize "org" and i cant import them.
I tried to find out how to add the org package but I didn't find anything helpful.
do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Are those dependencies on your classpath?

Comment: There is no single "org package". You need to add the Apache Commons Codec to the dependencies of your module (how you do it depends on the build system you're using).

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html.

Comment: can you explain more about how I add the dependencies?
what do you mean by "build system"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHbiY1i4ivc) and it worked for me.
Basically I went to [this site](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi) , downloaded the binaries version , then file->project structure->libraries and I added what i downloaded